# Force reset promise when re-activated

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm attempting to have an async function that resets if it's recalled. This function is linked to multiple buttons, and triggers a div acting as a notification overlay box.

I would like, when the callAlert() function is called again, it resets the timeout on clearAlert(). I attempted to add 1500 ms when the newAlert is called, but I'm assuming that when any of the buttons (which trigger callAlert()) is clicked, it's already moved onto the clearAlert() promise. Either that, or I end up with a longer and longer wait time as it accumulates.

Any advise would be great.

```
let alertActive = false;
let alertCd = 0;

function newAlert(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            alert_pop.classList.remove("alert_pop");
            alertActive=true;
            alertCd = 1500
            resolve();
        } , 100);
    });
}

function clearAlert(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            alert_pop.classList.add("alert_pop");
            alert_string.innerHTML="";
            resolve();
         } , alertCd);
         alertActive=false;
    });
}

async function callAlert(){
        await newAlert();
        await clearAlert();
}
```

Comment: 1. Save the timeoutID [returned by `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). 2. Any time a new alert needs to be created, [cancel the last timer using `clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout), then create a new timeout. 3. If you need to cancel an existing timer (based on description, you do not), use `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: Would clearTimeout() finish the promise on clearAlert()?

Comment: It would not. ...Does it need to? `clearAlert()` creates its own Promise and tries to set its own timeout, I'm not sure why. You should change `clearAlert()` not to return a Promise. It doesn't need one. First, in `newAlert()`, save `resolve` or `reject` from the active Promise to a scope that is accessible by `clearAlert()`. Then, in `clearAlert()`, call `clearTimeout()` and `resolve()` or `reject()` (depending on what you're trying to do).

Comment: Updated to this, and it seems to be doing the trick - thank you!

Could you post as an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the promise returned by the first `callAlert()` call, when a second call extends the timeout? Should it be rejected as soon as it has been superseeded by a newer call? Should it be resolved only when the alert finally closes?

Comment: @KrisWest will do. Wanted to help but didn't have the time to write out a full answer. In other news, weren't you at 1 reputation just yesterday? Nice job, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Aha; yes, I was. Using other people's questions as a learning experience for myself by troubleshooting simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating a resetable timer

If you want to create a timer that can be reset,

1. Save the timeoutID returned by `setTimeout()`.
2. Any time a new alert needs to be created, cancel the last timer using `clearTimeout()`, then create a new timeout.

### Cancelling the timer

If you need to cancel an existing timer, use `clearTimeout()`. Right now, `clearAlert()` creates its own Promise and tries to set its own timeout. You should change `clearAlert()` not to return a Promise (at least, for now. It looks like you may be trying to delay the cancellation).

First, in `newAlert()`, save resolve or reject from the active Promise to a scope that is accessible by `clearAlert()`. Then, in `clearAlert()`, call `clearTimeout()` and `resolve()` or `reject()` (depending on what you're trying to do).

Comment: When canceling the timer, you shouldn't leave the promise unresolved though. Better reject it.

Comment: @Bergi agreed. I think that's the last paragraph

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that a JavaScript function is not called more than once every few seconds, you can run wrap it in the “debounce” function available in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce).

here is a well explained [example](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/lodash-debounce-example/).

Comment: Agreed, this is indeed an debounce function